# i am unable to read from the serial port of my ubuntu machine using python

Tags: python, pyserial

```
from serial import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate = 9600, timeout=1)
while 1:
    Data = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
print(Data)
```

Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'

Comment: Change your file's name from `serial.py` to something else.

Comment: Try changing `from serial import serial` to `import serial` per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267070/no-module-named-serial .

Comment: did that but same error

Comment: @BurhanKhalid : you mean my python file where i have written my code ?? i mean the code above which i posted ??

Comment: @shoravsuriyal Burhan's comment actually sounds correct.  The error suggests your program is confusing some user-defined module in your project with `pyserial`.  Python packaging/modules are annoying, but I'd suggest reading up on it.

Comment: i solved the problem...actually i installed the wrong library..i should install pyserial instead of serial....my bad