# Cant import module from python console unless entered via CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I installed a module with command

```
pip install serial
```

And it appears to have been successful.

I can open up a cmd and enter `python` and then `import serial` without any issues.

However, if I open up either

- Python 3.6 (64-bit)
- Python 3.6 (32-bit)
- IDLE (Python 3.6 64-bit)
- IDLE (Python 3.6 32-bit)

And try the same command (`import serial`) I get an annoying

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'serial'

What is going on here?

Comment: What does `python --version` show from cmd?

Comment: See if this helps you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267070/no-module-named-serial. Not saying it is duplicate just if this solves your purpose

Comment: @MadPhysicist It says `Python 2.7.15` - I guess my path is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install it with python 3.6.
try these

```
pip3.6 install serial
```

or

```
python3.6 -m pip install serial
```

Comment: `pip3` may also work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have more then one Python shell on your PC.
According to your comment , you installed the module on python 2.7.15 and try to work with it in python 3.6.

1. Install it on the same shell you will use it (using pip command is most convenient)
2. Configure your IDE to use the correct python shell

Please note that if you use pip from the command line , without entering the python shell , you will not be able to know , on which shell it was installed.

In case you have multiple python shell , you need to enter the python shell and then use pip command.