# I can't import serial package in pycharm

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial, serial-communication

I am trying do receive data from arduino serial port. I write code like this when i run this code in cmd (after write python) this work properly. but i am try do this in pycharm `AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'Serial'`. i research about this bug. i try some method like uninstall pyserial then reinstall pyserial but it doesnt work. i install pyserial package like this `pip install pyserial` and also i try `python -m pip install pyserial` but it still dont work. i need your help

my code is here:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM3',9600)
ser.flushInput()

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        print(decoded_bytes)

    except:
        print("Keyboard interrupt")
        break
```

and also i try from serial import Serial i get this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial' from 'serial' (C:\Users\NU-telebe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\lib\site-packages\serial\__init__.py)
enter code here
```

Comment: check if maybe a dupe of this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267070/no-module-named-serial

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `PyCharm` has special function in settings to install modules for current project. OR you could check full path to Python used by project - `print( sys.executable )` and later use `/full/path/to/python -m pip install ...` to install module in correct Python.

Comment: Why not try destroying/reconstructing the pycharm project instead of just uninstalling/reinstalling pyserial?

Comment: There are 2 serial libraries the one i assume your trying to use is pyserial lib, but you probably installed the serial lib. Pip uninstall serial and pip install pyserial